# How I can change the model attribute name on ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

> I want to change false variable name to new one, so I created the true and new one but the old and false one stil stay!

- > How can remove the false one

  `irb(main):001:0> item = Item.last
  Item Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "items".* FROM "items" ORDER BY "items"."id" DESC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  => #<Item id: 6, title: "Make a cake for your darling", description: "She loves furit ", created_at: "2019-02-27 18:04:15", updated_at: "2019-02-27 18:04:15", user_id: 2, complated_at: nil, completed_at: nil>
  irb(main):002:0>`

> I made a typo mistake it must be "completed"

What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
rails g migration remove_complated_at_from_items complated_at:datetime
```

> this line generate those codes

```
class RemoveComplatedAtFromItems < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    remove_column :items, :complated_at, :datetime
  end
end
```

> my current schema.rb file

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2019_02_27_204841) do
  create_table "items", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.text "description"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.datetime "completed_at"
    t.datetime "complated_at"
  end
```

> now lets run rails db:migrate

`$ rails db:migrate`

```
== 20190227204841 RemoveComplatedAtFromItems: migrating =======================
-- remove_column(:items, :complated_at, :datetime)
   -> 0.0038s
== 20190227204841 RemoveComplatedAtFromItems: migrated (0.0039s) ==============
```

> Seems every things is okay! lets check it schema.rb!

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2019_02_27_204841) do
  create_table "items", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.text "description"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.datetime "completed_at"
  end
```

> All is good right now. Last to left lets check the one object!

```
 rails c
irb(main):001:0> item = Item.last
  Item Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "items".* FROM "items" ORDER BY "items"."id" DESC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<Item id: 6, title: "Make a cake for your darling", description: "She loves furit ", created_at: "2019-02-27 18:04:15", updated_at: "2019-02-27 18:04:15", user_id: 2, completed_at: nil>
```

> DONE!

Answer (score 2):

Don't delete column. Just rename it.

Create a new migration and put the code:

`rename_column :items, :complated_at, :completed_at`

Comment: thanks! :) For those trying this: I ran `rails g migration RenameColumnsComplatedAt` then changed the migration to be: `class RenameColumnsComplatedAt < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    rename_column :tasks, :complated_at, :completed_at
  end
end`

Answer (score 0):

Create a migration and use the `remove_column` method to alter your database.

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-remove_column